# Qt Creator cannot find -lQt5Quick

Tags: linux, qt, qt-creator

Hi I just installed Qt Creator in linux, before I used Qt Creator on Windows and everything worked fine. In linux I got this errors even if I just create new project and I don't make any changes.

```
skipping incompatible /home/***/Qt/5.3/gcc/lib/libQt5Quick.so when searching for -lQt5Quick
cannot find -lQt5Quick
skipping incompatible /home/***/Qt/5.3/gcc/lib/libQt5Qml.so when searching for -lQt5Qml
....
```

This error shows to all components like Widgets, Network, Gui..

Is Qt Creator don't see its own library?

Comment: you installed using "sudo"? Or you overwrite a previous installation?

Comment: Qt Creator is an IDE, it doesn't look for any libraries. You're probably talking of the output of qmake. You should also mention that the errors appear when you attempt to *build* the project, not merely when you *create* a new project.